# How to solve MySQL error: #1064 in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(Target) AS target FROM salesmen WHERE `Area Code` IN (SELECT `Area Code` FROM distributors_areas WHERE Regional_Manager IN (SELECT `Name` FROM `regional managers` WHERE ID = 0) OR WHERE Territory_Manager IN (SELECT Name FROM `territory managers` WHERE ID = 'TM_02'))
```

When running this query, I get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Territory_Manager IN (SELECT Name FROM `territory managers` WHERE ID = 'TM' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

There is no `or where` in SQL.  Just `or`:

```
SELECT SUM(s.Target) AS target
FROM salesmen s
WHERE s.`Area Code` IN
           (SELECT da.`Area Code`
            FROM distributors_areas da
            WHERE da.Regional_Manager IN
                      (SELECT rm.`Name`
                       FROM `regional managers` rm
                       WHERE rm.ID = 0
                      ) OR 
                  da.Territory_Manager IN
                      (SELECT tm.Name
                       FROM `territory managers` tm
                       WHERE tm.ID = 'TM_02'
                      )
           );
```

I think I mentioned on an earlier question that you should use table aliases in your query.  *I am repeating this advice here!*.  When you have more than one table reference, you should always be in the habit of including table aliases and qualifying all column names, to avoid common, preventable mistakes in your queries.

Comment: Sorry. I have to submit a school project tomorrow and lots of work is still left. I am sticking with my style of writing queries for now. I will follow your suggestion in my later projects. Thanks for helping me out on both occasions btw.